# main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol public: __cdecl

Tags: c++, qt, class, qt5, linker-errors

I'm trying to write a simple class in C++ with Qt5. I can't figure out this error comes from :

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ItemModel::ItemModel(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (??0ItemModel@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
>       debug\AMWS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

**Test.pro**

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = Test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += \
    main.h \
    itemmodel.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    itemmodel.cpp
```

**itemmodel.h**

```
#ifndef ITEMMODEL_H
#define ITEMMODEL_H

#include <string>

class ItemModel
{
public:
    ItemModel(std::string sku);
protected:
    std::string SKU;
};

#endif // ITEMMODEL_H
```

**itemmodel.cpp**

```
#include "itemmodel.h"

using namespace std;

ItemModel::ItemModel(string sku) : SKU(sku)
{

}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "itemmodel.h"

#endif // MAIN_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ItemModel product("dummy");

    cout << "Great!!!" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is not valid C code. Why did you tag it?

Comment: That looks like a Visual Studio linking error. The example compiles fine as-is with Visual Studio 2015. What are compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Qt5 on Windows

Comment: Qt5 is not a compiler.  GNU g++ and Visual Studio are compilers.

Comment: because I didn't configure Qt5. I just compiled in. So I guess VS compiler

Comment: Try to delete the complete build folder (Makefiles included) and recompile. Sometime Qt apps have weird linker errors due to makefiles not being updated by qmake when they should.

Comment: @this.lau_ you're right! your advice works fine! would be good if you could turn it in a reply

Comment: @Steve, sure I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the complete build folder (Makefiles included) and recompile.

Sometime Qt apps have weird linker errors due to makefiles not being updated by qmake when they should.